# Magento - Attribute price should fetch on frontend on currency change

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.9.1

By default in magento for multiple currency a conversion factor is used to convert price to particular currency, But I want there should be three static price for three currency, attribute price should get fetched in front end when selecting a currency.

Please help

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Using  this **$_coreHelper->currency()** function you can get

```
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();

$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currentCurrencyCode)->getSymbol();

$_coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');
echo $currentCurrencyCode;
 echo $_coreHelper->currency($yourPrice),false,true); ?>
```